# Installing Mavericks 10.9.4

Tags: macos, firewire

I have a 2011 MBP that I use as a studio computer, with it I use an archaic Mbox2 Pro soundcard with Firewire.
The drivers for the soundcard are compatible with Mavericks 10.9.4 (the one in App store is version 10.9.5, which produce some irregular behavior). The OSX version I've used until now is the latest version of Mountain Lion, so I'd like to upgrade.

Is there any way of downloading an older version of Mavericks (for example 10.9.1) and then use the combo update packages available at the developer site?

Answer (score 1):

You can only download it at all if you have it in your Purchase History on the App Store, & even then you'd get 10.9.5

Other than that, you'd need to find a friend who archives OS versions meticulously.
If you can get hold of 10.9.anything, you can then use the combo updater to 10.9.4 from Apple.